# How to transfer the ASP:Membership tables to DotNetNuke?

Tags: dotnetnuke

Does anyone know how to transfer the asp.net membership tables (roles, profiles, users, membership, etc) to dotnetnuke without losing any users.

Thanks,
XaiSoft

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the accounts over to DotNetNuke from a different system, but you will have a few things that you must do.

1. You must update the DotNetNuke web.config to have the same Validation and Decryption keys as the application that actually created the users.
2. You must update the membership provider in the DNN web.config to have the same application name as the external system
3. Lastly you must insert entries and information into the Users, UserPortals, and UserRoles tables to actually "grant access" to DotNetNuke.